# Build a semicolon delimited list of emails in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

We frequently need to email all application users regarding notifications of various sorts. For various reasons (junk mail filters, policy limitations etc), we need to restrict the number of users a notification is sent to on one email. If the numbers of emails increases over a given number, another email needs to be sent.

```
DECLARE @emails varchar(max)
with EmailList AS
(
    SELECT row_number() over(order by email) as Seq, 
    Email from ApplicationUser
)
select @emails = COALESCE(@emails + ';', ' ') +  email from EmailList where seq between 1 and 99;
```

The block above gives me the list but it has the flaw of someone checking how many users are present and manually select the subsequent groups.

How do I select as many rows as needed until all the email rows have been selected.

Comment: This sort of business logic really belongs in a service layer and kept out of the DB.

Comment: This is more of an adhoc query. Having a screen for sending release notification emails to users would be quite nice though! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL 2017, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select string_agg(email, ';')
from (select row_number() over(order by email) as seqnum, au.*
      from ApplicationUser au
     ) au
group by (seqnum - 1) / 100;
```

In earlier versions, you need to do this using XML:

```
with e as (
      select (row_number() over(order by email) - 1) / 100 as grp,
             au.*
      from ApplicationUser au
     ) 
select stuff( (select ';' + email
               from e
               where e.grp = g.grp
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
             ) as emails
from (select distinct grp from e) g
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using an older version of SQL Server and the second query works. I just had to remove the extra au after the CTE